# Can I open a bank accounts in Germany with a fiktionsbescheinigung?

Tags: germany, banking

Fiktionsbescheinigung is the temporary residence permit given to people in waiting to get their residence permit.

I would Like to know if it is possible to open a bank account with a German bank using this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your passport as ID proof. Your residency status is not relevant for them.

Comment: This answer is not correct: [Our accounts and services - Berliner Sparkasse](https://www.berliner-sparkasse.de/en/home/expats/getting-started.html): **Documents needed to open your bank account**: *Registration of your residence  [Meldebescheinigung/Anmeldung] issued by city hall (Bürgeramt) ... If applicable: Residence permit [Aufenthaltserlaubnis] issued by the immigration office (Ausländerbehörde)*

Comment: @MarkJohnson, in principle, people can get bank accounts as non-residents, or even without being in-country. But banks are required to know their customers (money laundering regulations) and the **normal** process for a **normal** account assumes registered residents.

Answer (score -2):

> I would Like to know if it is possible to open a bank account with a German bank using this?

Yes, a **Fiktionsbescheinigung** assumes that a residence permit will be granted.

See **Documents needed to open your bank account** in the link below:

- [Our accounts and services - Berliner Sparkasse](https://www.berliner-sparkasse.de/en/home/expats/getting-started.html)

Comment: You are linking one (fairly large and popular) bank. Other banks have similar but not identical requirement. One key document would be the *Meldebescheinigung*.